# How are UK undergraduate Master's degrees (MMath/MPhys/MEng) perceived in the US for graduate school admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, united-states, united-kingdom

In the UK, it is possible to do either a 3 years long BSc degree or a 4 years long MMath/MPhys/MEng degree. Both types of degrees are considered to be undergraduate degrees and it is likely that the thesis requirement for MMath/MPhys/MEng is closer to the requirements for a BS thesis (than MS thesis) in the US.

The standard credit requirement for the completion of the BSc is 360 CATS (this should be roughly equivalent to 90 US credit hours according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_Accumulation_and_Transfer_Scheme). The MMath/MPhys/MEng degrees have a 480 CATS requirement that should be approximately equivalent to 120 US credit hours. It seems like in the US the requirement for the completion of a Bachelor's degree is 120+ credit hours.

I know that there are differences in terms of how the graduate programs in the US are structured depending on whether one enters with a Bachelor's degree or a Master's degree (for example, the comprehensive examinations need to be passed earlier by those entering with a Master's degree and the credit requirement is different). My primary question is whether the UK undergraduate MMath/MPhys/MEng degrees would be considered equivalent to the US BS degree or MS degree during graduate school admission.

Comment: 'there is no thesis requirement'  If it's an MEng accredited by the Engineering Council as meeting the educational requirements for Chartered Engineer status, or an MPhys accredited by the Institute of Physics as meeting the educational requirements for Chartered Physicist status, then there _is_ a thesis requirement.

Comment: Came here to say the same thing as @DanielHatton. I wrote a dissertation in both the third and fourth year of my MPhys.

Comment: @DanielHatton I edited the question.